# Remap touch pad zones for Thinkpad Yoga?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, thinkpad, multi-touch

I have one of the new Thinkpads (Thinkpad Yoga S1) with the integrated touch pad which acts as what used be the dedicated left, right, and middle buttons.

I am trying to configure my touch pad in this behavior, so that the top part of the touch pad does not move the cursor, rather clicking one of these regions would act as the button. Ideally, the bottom sliver of the touch pad would be dedicated for left/right click, as well.

I'd also like to have three finger gestures enabled, if possible.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using help from [here](https://gist.github.com/tfg13/7628614), I was able to partially get what I desire. The top portion of the touch pad does not move the cursor, but the middle button doesn't work.

Comment: Adding to my last comment, the bottom right click button is very slim and hard to quickly press on the first try.